# SQL database standard way of designing a table

Tags: sql, database-design

There is an argument between me and my colleague in term of the design of a table inside a SQL database. The objective of the table is to store the value of different type of parameters base on the date and time.

For my suggestion is to create the table as below:

```
id  date        time    temperature pressure  duration  flowrate    steps
1   1/27/2018   11:13:00    24.5    0.343     57        8          pumping start
2   1/28/2018   12:13:00    25.4    0.452     788       10         pumping end
3   1/29/2018   13:13:00    24.5    3.342     332       6          pumping start
4   1/30/2018   14:13:00    30.5    4.323     33        3          vacuum start
5   1/31/2018   15:13:00    24.5    0.358     232       8          pumping start
```

As you can see, the 'tags' are represent different parameters, which each of them has different data type: double, int, text, etc.

My arguments are:

- we should not store numbers in text
- should not store multiple types in one column
- a query can be complicated, you might use a lot of 'When', 'And' in the clause
- need to convert the value from text to type of numbers when do calculations

As the idea of my colleague, the table should design as below:

```
id  date        time        tags        value(use text data type)
1   1/27/2018   11:13:00    temperature 24.5
2   1/27/2018   12:13:00    pressure    0.343
3   1/27/2018   13:13:00    duration    57
4   1/27/2018   14:13:00    flowrate    8
5   1/27/2018   15:13:00    pressure    9
6   1/27/2018   16:13:00    temperature 30.1
7   1/27/2018   17:13:00    temperature 23.4
8   1/27/2018   18:13:00    steps       pumping start
9   1/27/2018   19:13:00    steps       pumping end
```

His arguments are:

- each tag is independent in term of timing
- no structure modification when we add a tag
- reduce the size of the base

Apparently, my words are not enough to convince him, well, perhaps I am wrong in this case. So I need you advise on which is the best practice? and Why? It will be better to give some official reference link about standards/normalization about this, so that I make my words stronger.

Comment: No brainer. You're recording observations. Splitting observations over multiple rows adds complexity in almost any use case imaginable. If temperature, pressure, flow rate, etc. were _different observations_, then his design would make sense. Given the nature of the data, yours is better.

Comment: his model is the EAV anti-pattern which should be avoided whenever possible.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model

Comment: @Gene Thanks for your advice. could you explain me more on your comments：“If temperature, pressure, flow rate, etc. were different observations, then his design would make sense.”? Perhaps with examples if possible, thanks.

Comment: @Jasen Thanks. So we should never use EAV table, right?

Comment: the wikipedia page lists reasons for and against,  in my experience generally it causes pain.

Comment: @Jasen Thanks for sharing your experience.

Comment: I agree that the first design is better. If temperature, pressure, duration, flow rate and steps are separate observations, I would rather make separate tables for them, or even make those columns nullable, than use the second design.

Comment: @reaanb Thanks for the comments, in my case, these parameters are recorded in one observation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are really two separable questions here.

The first is whether or not two parameters like temperature and pressure should be bound to the same date and time by placing them in the same row.  It sounds like, in the real world, these two parameters come out of one observation, that has one date and time.  So binding them together is both more efficient and better data management.

The second question is whether making the database structure independent of the specific tags is a good idea or a bad idea.  Your friends design is indeed very much like the EAV pattern or anti-pattern depending on your point of view.  This is a very deep philosophical debate, one that has passionate partisans on both sides.  It is unlikely to be resolved between you and your friend.

I'm firmly in the anti EAV camp.  I'm forced to admit that there are some exceptional cases where EAV turns out to be the right way to go.  These are cases where analyzing the subject matter to discover the data is impossible or impractical, and you have to capture data before you understand the scope of the project.

Most of the time, data analysis of the subject matter is eminently practical and worthwhile, even though time consuming.  The result is a database whose logical structure mirrors the conceptual structure of the real world.  When the information requirements change (such as a new tag), the structure of the database changes.

Changing the structure of the database is labor intensive, and transforming the existing data is hard.  But the result is much better data management, where the data definitions inside the DBMS are helping you with data management.  It's both better use of machine resources and better use of human resources.

So I think you are right in the argument, but unlikely to prevail over your friend.  Your friend would rather do his own data management, without the DBMS helping or hindering.  Good luck to him. He's going to need it when his projects get beyond the beginner stage.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, it help me a lot. Yes, all these parameters are recorded in one observation. I like your view of data analysis, it's key to me in this case as there will be many of them.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the best way:

```
id  date        time    temperature pressure  duration  flowrate    steps
1   1/27/2018   11:13:00    24.5    0.343     57        8          pumping start
2   1/28/2018   12:13:00    25.4    0.452     788       10         pumping end
3   1/29/2018   13:13:00    24.5    3.342     332       6          pumping start
4   1/30/2018   14:13:00    30.5    4.323     33        3          vacuum start
5   1/31/2018   15:13:00    24.5    0.358     232       8          pumping start
```

Because With the second design could has less columns but It has so many repetead data, the records 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 has the same information because is the same record, this could make the database more heavy, and with repeated data.

I hope be helpful.

Comment: Thanks for the answer